# Sending Model issue ASP.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Controller httpGet Action :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CalculCom(int id) 
        {
            CalcCom calc = new CalcCom();
            ComModel com = calc.CalculCom(id, 10, 2011);
            return View(com);
        }
```

This is my View :

```
// Some code to show my model attribute

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ben)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.centre)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.mtn_brut)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.mtn_net)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.mtn_rs)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.quitaList) // this is a list 
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.val_rs)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.versNum)

    <input type="submit" value="Valider"/> 
}
```

This is my controller HttpPost Action :

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CalculCom(ComModel model)
        {
            //some code
            foreach (ComModel.quita qi in model.quitaList)
            {
                var quita = db.QUITA.Find(qi.n_quita);
                quita.VERSNUM = vers.VERSNUM;
                db.Entry(quita).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

ComModel :

```
public class ComModel
{
    public int versNum { get; set; }
    public decimal mtn_brut { get; set; }
    public decimal mtn_net { get; set; }
    public decimal mtn_rs { get; set; }
    public decimal val_rs { get; set; }
    public string ben { get; set; }
    public int centre { get; set; } 
    public List<quita> quitaList = new List<quita>();

    public struct quita
    {
        public decimal mtn_com { get; set; }
        public decimal mtn_net { get; set; }
        public decimal mtn_ttc { get; set; }
        public decimal comp_prime { get; set; }
        public decimal mtn_fq { get; set; }
        public decimal mtn_tot { get; set; }

        public int n_quita { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So What I'm trying to do Is:

1. getting the Model (HttpGet Action)
2. show my model the then user will decide it to validate the model or not.
3. If Model is valide then I will save it to database.

The problem when user Click on submit button the model is sent but the items in `quitaList` was missing , After sending , in my HttpPost Controler, `quitaList` was empty

So how to fix it ? Also is there any other ways to do that, showing modal before saving it to database, instead using From to send model?

Comment: Can you also show the code for ComModel?

Answer (score 0):

For get list back in model during form post you need to loop through the list like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ben)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.centre)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.mtn_brut)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.mtn_net)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.mtn_rs)
@for(int i=0;i<Model.quitaList.Count;i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.quitaList[i].mtn_com)
}
 @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.val_rs)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.versNum)

<input type="submit" value="Valider"/>
```

}

This will give list back in model, but note that it will only contain value of "mnt_com" property. if you want all property value then you need to define all same as in above code in the loop.

Comment: Is there any other possible way like using some global variable pointer ?